# Is a MySQL commercial license required when selling a PHP-website that is hosted on WAMP?

Tags: licensing, commercial

Do I have to pay a commercial MySQL license to install WAMP with my PHP-script on the localhost of a company, asking monthly fee for it from the company? (The PHP script is a modified version of an open source script on Github). With other words I'm selling my PHP script to the company and use WAMP to load it on their localhost.

I know WAMP is free for commercial use, but MySQL also comes with a commercial license... I know it is open source GPL but the site doesn't describe my situation.

I already read everything on their website so a link to their license page is not necessary. I hope someone can give me the answer on my specific situation as it is unclear for me right now.

Comment: Under what license do you sell your script? An open source license or a commercial license that doesn't allow the company to redistribute the script? And if the latter, under what license is the original script provided on github?

Comment: A commercial license at the moment, but I could go with selling them an open source license if that makes things easier, as longs as I'm still allowed to get paid for installing it at their localhost. The original script itself is open source under apache 2.0 version license.

Comment: A commercial license at the moment, but I could go with selling them an open source license if that makes things easier, as longs as I'm still allowed to get paid for installing it at their localhost. The original script itself is open source under apache 2.0 version license.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but your modified script needs to be distributed under the Apache 2.0 license (otherwise you are violating the copyright on the original script). This does not prohibit you from selling the script or from charging a fee for installation and support.

Comment: Thanks for telling me! I almost made a mistake there. Does this mean I have to include the text of the Apache License 2.0 or inform the company in another way? Or this it just mean I can't forbid them to distribute it also?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I'm not sure you're right.  I'd always understood Apache 2.0 to be a weak copyleft licence, and having re-read it, I can't find any provision in it requiring derivative works to be licensed under Apache 2.0.

Comment: I just looked it up and the answer can be found here: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/2782/apache-2-0-license-notice-changelog TLDR: You have to log all modifications in a Notice.txt file. And you can license the company under you're own license by choice. I hope someone can still answer my question about the MySQL license regarding my situation

Comment: "asking monthly fee for it from the company" - What will you do if (when) they stop paying the monthly fee? GPL means you must also allow them to copy the GPL parts, such as MySQL, even if they stop paying the fee. I'm not sure about the Apache licensed parts. Your licensing problem might disappear if you sell them the software (already allowed under GPL and Apache) and a support contract instead.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, ask the owner with the full details of what you want to do. Only they can answer authoritatively. Or a lawyer specializing in this abstruse area of law.